# Nomencl: how to remove indentation in two columns multiline entries

Tags: indentation, two-column, nomenclature

I'm using the `nomencl` package to write a two columns list of terms I frequently use in my thesis.
Everything looks fine except that I don't like that whenever the explanation of a term takes more than one line a small indentation is inserted.
What I have now is something that looks like:

```
MyTerm detailed explanation of my term.
   and here follows the second line.
```

I'd like to have is so that it looks like:

```
MyTerm detailed explanation of my term.
and here follows the second line.
```

Can someone please help me? I've tried to go through the documentation of the package but I couldn't really get much out of it!

Comment: I just built a minimal working example and can not reproduce your problem. I get the behaviour you want straight away. You need to provide an example, stating your document class and possible other packages that may influence indention. How do you switch to twocolumn mode?

Answer (score 1):

In the following example I used print the nomenclature in `onecolumn` mode and in `twocolumn` mode. The mode `twocolumn` is generated in two ways. The first one uses the command `\twocolumn` and the second one the environment `multicols*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\begin{document}
Text
\nomenclature{WYSIWYG}{Is an acronym for What You See Is What You Get. The term is used in computing to describe a system in which content (text and graphics)}
\printnomenclature
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\printnomenclature
\end{multicols*}
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

After the correct compilation:
pdflatex file.tex
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls
pdflatex file.tex

I get the correct output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you need to change the settings of the list environment hard coded in `nomencl.sty`. But I don't see something that is two-columns specific (as the title of your question stated), so maybe I missed something.

```
    % This is test.tex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{nomencl}

    \makeatletter
    \def\thenomenclature{%
      \@ifundefined{chapter}%
      {
        \section*{\nomname}
        \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
      }%
      {
        \chapter*{\nomname}
        \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
      }%

      \nompreamble
      \list{}{%
        \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
        \leftmargin=0pt
        \itemindent=\dimexpr\itemsep+\labelwidth\relax
        \itemsep\nomitemsep
        \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
    \makeatother

    \makenomenclature

    \begin{document}
    Some text \nomenclature{LONG}{This is a long long long long long long
      long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      long long long text}

    \printnomenclature

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I explained it wrong.

Comment: @LucaCerone Maybe. But does my answer fit to your needs?